# How can I learn website/webpage design

Tags: website-design, resource-recommendations

I asked the closed https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16602/how-can-or-should-i-design-my-personal-and-professional-sites, and one of the comments was that if the commenter stumbled upon any of my sites, that commenter would conclude I knew nothing about design.

So can I ask resources, whether available from Safari or elsewhere, on how I can better learn design?

Comment: Poorly researched. Theres tons of resources including answers on here. Come back with a specific question please.

Comment: Not wanting to pile on, but you might find the answers and discussion to these questions useful: [How would I know how good a designer I am?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13808/how-would-i-know-how-good-of-a-designer-i-am/13812#13812) has many tips on self-appraisal and spotting areas needing improvement, and [Why do people keep telling me my site looks awful?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8549/) has a pile of tips many of which are widely relevant.

Comment: As for the less than friendly response you've received (sorry about that!), it'll help if you can whittle down what you're doing to specific types of problem that can be answered in a page. This is a question that is more often answered in whole book, or even whole shelves of books! And your other question seemed to be at the very start of problem-solving. Ideally, the point to seek help from strangers is more like "I'm trying to do X and Y, but no matter what I do, Z doesn't work - here's what I've tried".

Comment: I wasn't trying to be rude by my comments. Please don't take anything personally. My opinion regarding a design is not to be seen as anything other than my opinion. I've had work literally spit upon. Taking criticism is part of being a designer. As User568458 points out, direct questions may provide specific answers which may be helpful to you.